# How to extract multiple data points from multiple strings in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataset that consists of thousands of entries such as the following:

```
[{'country': {'id': '1A', 'value': 'Arab World'},
  'date': '2016',
  'decimal': '0',
  'indicator': {'id': 'SP.POP.TOTL', 'value': 'Population, total'},
  'value': None},
 {'country': {'id': '1A', 'value': 'Arab World'},
  'date': '2015',
  'decimal': '0',
  'indicator': {'id': 'SP.POP.TOTL', 'value': 'Population, total'},
  'value': '392168030'},
 {'country': {'id': '1A', 'value': 'Arab World'},
  'date': '2014',
  'decimal': '0',
  'indicator': {'id': 'SP.POP.TOTL', 'value': 'Population, total'},
  'value': '384356146'},
```

....17020-ish rows later.....

```
{'country': {'id': 'XH', 'value': 'IDA blend'},
      'date': '1960',
      'decimal': '0',
      'indicator': {'id': 'SP.POP.TOTL', 'value': 'Population, total'},
      'value': '163861743'},
     ...]
```

I want to create a *DataFrame* using *pandas* such that y-axis = 'id' and x-axis = 'date', with 'value' being the stored value. I can't figure out the best way to approach this...

EDIT:
Imagine a sheet with just numbers ('value' from the dataset). The x-axis columns would be the extracted date and the y-axis rows would be the country id ('id'). The final object would be a dataset that is y*x in size. The numbers would all be of type 'float'.

EDIT 2:
The dataset represents ~304 countries from 1960 - 2016, so there are approximately 304 * 56 = 17024 entries in the dataset. I need to store the 'value' (where for entry 2, value = 392168030) with respect to each country and date.

EDIT 3:
Using the above data, an example output data set would be structured thusly:

```
        2016 .       2015 .       2014 .   ...       1960
1A .    None .  392168030    384356146 .   ...          w
...
XH .       x            y            z          163861743
```

Comment: Can you edit your question with how you expect the data to look like in excel or any other tabular format?  It is a bit unclear how you want to handle `indicator` or `decimal`.

Comment: @Fomalhaut-C rather than explain what you want, can you show an example of what the desired output should be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First extract the information from origin dataset:

```
dataset = [{'country': {'id': '1A', 'value': 'Arab World'},
           'date': '2016',
           'decimal': '0',
           'indicator': {'id': 'SP.POP.TOTL', 'value': 'Population, total'},
           'value': None},
           {'country': {'id': '1A', 'value': 'Arab World'},
           'date': '2015',
           'decimal': '0',
           'indicator': {'id': 'SP.POP.TOTL', 'value': 'Population, total'},
           'value': '392168030'},
           {'country': {'id': '1A', 'value': 'Arab World'},
           'date': '2014',
           'decimal': '0',
           'indicator': {'id': 'SP.POP.TOTL', 'value': 'Population, total'},
           'value': '384356146'},
           {'country': {'id': 'XH', 'value': 'IDA blend'},
           'date': '1960',
           'decimal': '0',
           'indicator': {'id': 'SP.POP.TOTL', 'value': 'Population, total'},
           'value': '163861743'}]

df = [[entry['country']['id'], entry['date'], entry['value']] for entry in dataset]
df = pd.DataFrame(df, columns=['id','date','value'])
```

Then pivot the datafrme:

```
df = df.pivot(index='id',columns='date',values='value')
```

The output:

```
date       1960       2014       2015  2016
id                                         
1A         None  384356146  392168030  None
XH    163861743       None       None  None
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to make a guess about how the "thousands of entries" might look but I came up with this possible solution.

```
entry1 = {
      'country': {'id': '1A', 'value': 'Arab World'},
      'date': '2016',
      'decimal': '0',
      'indicator': {'id': 'SP.POP.TOTL', 'value': 'Population, total'},
      'value': None
    }

entry2 = {
  'country': {'id': '1B', 'value': 'Another World'},
  'date': '2016',
  'decimal': '0',
  'indicator': {'id': 'SP.POP.TOTL', 'value': 'Population, total'},
  'value': None
}

entries = [entry1, entry2]

countries_index = []
date_cols = []

countries_index = []
date_cols = []
for entry in entries:
    date_cols.append(entry['date'])
    countries_index.append(entry['country']['id'])

import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(date_cols, columns=['date'], index=countries_index)
```

This creates a data frame,`df` which looks like this...

```
    date
1A  2016
1B  2016
```

Comment: Really appreciate your help. I made a clarification in the question with a better representative sample of the data. I suspect you're on to the right solution by isolating the dates and country names, which I have done as well. But how could I go about saving each 'value' with respect to those 2 axes?